# Is there a way to refresh view dynamically ASP NET CORE MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a trouble while developing a little project. In this page where I have a form, i want to show the name of the files that are being chosen with the file
input on an unordered-list:

[image]

This is my view code:

[image]

And this is my ViewModel code:

[image]

The problem is that from what i can see, the property `ImagesToUpload` is null when is evaluated in that if, but is never evaluated again even though I choose images from the input and they are added to that property

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to add filenames to `<div id="imagenes"></div>` when file input changes?If so,here is a demo:
View:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="AgregarInmueble">
    <input type="file" multiple asp-for="ImagesToUpload" />
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</form>
<div id="imagenes">

</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
    $("#ImagesToUpload").change(function () {
        $("#imagenes").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < $("#ImagesToUpload")[0].files.length; ++i) {
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode($("#ImagesToUpload")[0].files.item(i).name);
            para.appendChild(node);
            document.getElementById("imagenes").appendChild(para);
        }
      
    })
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wanted something like that. Is it only possible with JS right? Also, i would like to know how can i upload many files that belong to different folders. For example i choose 3 files from a folder, then click again on the button and choose 2 from another one (when i do it atm, it overwrites my list of files and keeps the lasts one chosen)

Comment: No,you cannot choose files from different folders,and what you want is client side demand,so use js is good and we usually use js with client side demand.